# input and check of values from input box

Tags: excel

please help where is the error.
loop without IF?
I need to load the code, check the first 2 values match the cell. Check that you do not duplicate in column A. And retrieve the codes until the required number is reached.
Thank you
My Code:

```
Sub novy()

Dim aText(1)  As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim vstup As String
vstup = InputBox(aText(x))
Set hledat = Range("A:A").Find(what:=vstup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If vstup = "" Then ' in case the use press "Cancel"
       i = MsgBox("Chcete ukončit načítání?", vbYesNo)
        Select Case i

       Case vbYes

        Exit Sub

       Case vbNo

           Call novy

    End Select
ElseIf Left(vstup, 2) <> Range("D3").Formula Then
i = MsgBox("jiný modul!", vbExclamation)
ElseIf hledat Is Nothing Then

For n = 1 To 10
aText(1) = "Načti kód"
Sheets("data").Select
aLastRow = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For x = 1 To 1
    Cells(aLastRow, x) = vstup

  Next
Cells(10, 9) = n
'MsgBox n
Next n
MsgBox "Bedna je hotová"


Else
i = MsgBox("modul byl už načten!", vbExclamation)


   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: First step to seeing the problem: fix your [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation).

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the the two last for loops. you dont need 2 either with an "x" from 1 to 1..

```
For n = 1 To 10
aText(1) = "Načti kód"
Sheets("data").Select
aLastRow = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
Cells(aLastRow, 1) = vstup

Next
```